# Getting two paragraphs in different divs to line up

Tags: html

EDIT: I've found an own solution for this. I've posted it in the answer section.

I'm trying to get two paragraphs aligned on the bottom with one paragraph in an other div.

[image: img example]

```
<div class="left-div">
   <div class="img">
      <img src=img>
   </div>
   <div class="below-img-div">
      <p>This is a p</p>
      <p>this is a smaller p</p>
      <hr>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="right-div">
   <div class="img">
      <img src=img>
   </div>
   <div class="div-below-img2">
          <p>Also a p</p>
          <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="something-else">
   </div>
</div>
```

The img divs have a min-height. The left-div and right-div have `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`

I was thinking about adding a "something-else" div to the left-div to make it easier for when I populate it with more paragraphs. But the issue with aligning it with the paragraph in the right-div will remain.

I thought about creating margin at the top of `<p>Also a p</p>` but I'm afraid that it will mess up the alignment when dealing with different browser sizes.

Other solution would be making divs for every `<p>` in order to set the paragraph on the bottom of the div.

I've added a jsifddle, it's a little bit different: https://jsfiddle.net/8wxome41/

Comment: could you attach a jsfiddle link?

Comment: ofcourse, I just edited it into it

Comment: [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) would work great for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this try use CSS Grid:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  height: auto;
}

.column--left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 260px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.column--right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px auto 20px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed pink;
}

.box {
  
  border: 1px dashed silver;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="column--left">
     <!-- row #1 30px -->
     <div class="box">
        <img src=img>
     </div>
     <!-- row #2 260px -->
     <div class="box">
        <p>This is a p</p>
        <p>this is a smaller p</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column--right">
     <!-- row #1 30px -->
     <div class="box">
        <img src=img>
     </div>
     
     <!-- row #2 auto height -->
     <div class="box">
            <p>Also a p</p>
     </div>
     
     <!-- row #3 20px -->
     <div class="box">
      <p>some text</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but I want "Also a p" to be on the same line as "this is a smaller p".

Comment: to do this add an empty P tag before

Comment: an empty one you mean?

Comment: yes, it is. It will work in case you have 1 line of text if left column's first P tag

Comment: This is not working when I add a p on top of  "also a p". Also, the left p tags might get bigger. If that happens then "Also a p" still needs to be aligned. I think I'm going to have to use divs

Answer (score 0):

MY OWN SOLUTION:

really stupid but I found a way by adding a `<br>` tag. Not sure if this is best practises but it seems to do everything that I need.

```
   <div class="div-below-img2">
          <br>
          <p>Also a p</p>
          <hr>
   </div>
```

Comment: You have to be sure that BR tag has same paddings and margins as P tag

Comment: If you want separate div to 2 parts with fixed height you can use display: grid CSS prop and set 2 rows. Then set for inner blocks overflow property (hidden and scroll), and for upper block set text-wrap: no-wrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: What would be the difference between flex and grid? I'm using mainly flex now

Comment: Difference is quite big. CSS Grid is a new approach to make designs more flexible and simple to use

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov sorry, but what do you mean with upper and inner blocks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206055/discussion-between-number42-and-maksim-tikhonov).